# Not able to make Ajax call using jquery

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to call a Sample API from my JSP using jQuery Ajax, but I am not getting success. I dont know where am I wrong but even simple html page is not getting loaded.

Here is my code.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello
<div id="temp">

<a href="#" onclick="callGetApplicationDetails();" >Click Here</a>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function callGetApplicationDetails()
{
    $.ajax({
        url:"serverFile.jsp",
        type: "GET",
        dataType:'html',
        async: true,
        data:data,
        success: function(responseData) {
            if (responseData != null && callback != null) {

            alert('success');

            $('#temp').html(responseData);


            }
        },
        error: function(){

            alert('error');

            if (errorCallback !=null) errorCallback();
        }
    });     
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Even the alert is not popping up of success and failure.[image]

Pls help.

thanks
Hemish

Comment: where do you declare `callback` (the one you compare with null) ?

Comment: Use some kind of a development tool showing JS errors to figure out what the real problem is - Firebug for Firefox, Developer Tools for Chrome or similar.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel,I was kind of screwed and cudnt see this simple thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use firebug, and check that the request is making it to the server.